# Grub Installation Fail ( Ubuntu )

Tags: grub2

[image: Problem Image]

I Have a problem at the installation of Ubuntu 17.00 with windows 10 .

What is the problem please !!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that error message doesn't give much to work on other than "grub failed" but I do have a theory. Windows 10 tends to hibernate a portion of the disk in order to improve boot times however, this can often make the disk inaccessible. There might be a better option but I would go ahead and cancel the installation, boot back into Windows, hold down the `Left Shift` key while powering the OS down, and then try reinstalling Ubuntu. You also might want to check your BIOS settings to make sure you are in UEFI mode (if you can still boot off your installation media that way).

Another possible option would be to boot up in a live OS and install [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). It worked for me a few times in the past when I accidentally overwrote my Grub onto a USB stick when putting full install on the USB, Virtual Box is the way to go there.